# tab complete in bash / gnome terminal opens emacs instead

Tags: bash, linux-mint, gnome-terminal

Tab complete has stopped working in bash running in gnome-terminal, and in a pretty perplexing fashion. When I attempt to use tab complete on a partial path, two Emacs windows open with a completely unrelated file. E.g. :

```
$ ls Deskt[2] 12460
-r: command not found
[3] 12466
-r: command not found

ls: cannot access 'Deskt': No such file or directory
[2]-  Done                    emacs Documents/to_read.txt
[3]+  Done                    emacs Documents/to_read.txt
```

I guess I must have accidentally changed a shortcut somewhere? I checked shortcuts in gnome-terminal under Edit->Preferences->Shortcuts. Also checked .bashrc and nothing seems out of place. It's pretty frustrating not being able to use tab complete, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was here - I had added the following line to my .bash_aliases file: `alias read='emacs ~/Documents/to_read.txt'`

But apparently 'read' is the name of the bash command invoked when pressing the tab key. So this is why attempting to use tab complete opened a seemingly-unrelated text file.